# Is it possible to call "location" on rangerOfCharacterFromSet without dot notation in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, nsrange, nscharacterset

I am trying to write this without dot notation but can't figure it out:

```
[[textField text] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:someInstanceVar].location
```

I keep getting `bad receiver type NSRange (aka '_struct NSRange')`

Is this not possible?

Kind regards

Comment: You can't access a member of a struct in any other way.

Comment: Please check my update, I'm basically allowing only characters and spaces in my textfield. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: And you can't avoid structs, they're everywhere.

Comment: @LondonGuy: I have taken the liberty to rollback the question to its initial version (since the update had changed the question fundamentally). You are welcome to post another question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot call that without the dot.
`rangeOfCharacterFromSet` returns a `NSRange`, which is a plain C struct:

```
typedef struct _NSRange {
    NSUInteger location;
    NSUInteger length;
} NSRange;
```

and not an Objective-C object. `.location` accesses the first member of that struct
and is pure C syntax.
That has nothing to do with the dot-notation for properties, or with method calls.